# Asserting an actual value in C# using selenium and Nunit

Tags: c#, selenium, nunit

HI I'm using Nunit and Selenium web driver. I've used Java previously in the same context Im struggling to solve this line of code.

```
`string actualvalue = IWebElement searchInput =` `driver.FindElement(By.Id("sb_form_q"));`
```

Here's the rest of it.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Firefox;
using NUnit.Framework;

namespace SeleniumTests1
{
    [TestFixture]
    class SeleniumTest
    {
        [Test]
        public void Main(string[] args)
        {

            IWebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
            driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://www.bing.com/");
            driver.Manage().Window.Maximize();

            string actualvalue = IWebElement searchInput = driver.FindElement(By.Id("sb_form_q"));
            searchInput.SendKeys("Hello World");
            searchInput.SendKeys(Keys.Enter);

            Assert.AreEqual(actualvalue, "Hello World");
            driver.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Well yes, that's syntactically invalid... what are you trying to achieve? Maybe you just need two statements, one to declare and initialize `searchInput` and later another one to declare and initialize `actualValue`?

Comment: I'm fairly new to the C# so Im working on the basis of my Java knowledge. In this instance I want to see if the Hello world I've typed has actually been typed into the search after the search preferably.

Comment: Well this would be syntactically invalid in Java as well... the basics of declaring and initializing variables are pretty similar between C# and Java.

Comment: I've just checked my old java 

String actualValue = getDriver().findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='aboutSM']/div[1]/div[2]/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[2]")).getText();

is there a get text for Nunit or similar?

Comment: NUnit is irrelevant here - it's Selenium that you need to look at. It looks like it would probably just be `string actualValue = driver.FindElement(By.XPath".//*[@id='aboutSM']/div[1]/div[2]/table/tbody/‌​tr[2]/td[2]")).Text;`

Comment: Cool I spotted that one having a play about with them now. Thanks for your help. I think I might need to put a wait in as it failed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works for me:

```
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Firefox;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    public static class SeleniumTest
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            IWebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
            driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://www.bing.com/");
            driver.Manage().Window.Maximize();

            IWebElement searchInput = driver.FindElement(By.Id("sb_form_q"));
            searchInput.SendKeys("Hello World");
            searchInput.SendKeys(Keys.Enter);

            searchInput = driver.FindElement(By.Id("sb_form_q"));
            string actualvalue = searchInput.GetAttribute("value");

            Assert.AreEqual(actualvalue, "Hello World");
            driver.Close();
        }
    }
}
```